# Values are set to be added to dictionary but values dictionary does not contain the keys and values submitted

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to xamarin app development and to be honest, c# in general as i'm only a junior (this is my first big app) so if I provide too little information I apologise but ill try my best to explain my issue.

I have an interface which has a dictionary defined so it can be used between 2 different activity. 1 activity is to put the Keys and values into the dictionary and the other is to display the keys and values on the screen. Here is my Interface code :

```
public interface IItemList
{
    IDictionary<string,int> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

My main activity is to set add keys and values to the dictionary, here is the code for my main activity (don't worry about irrelevant mistakes in my code I deleted some irrelevant parts for this post):

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, IItemList
{

    int qtyPart1NewQty;
    //Value of all qntys
    int value = 0;

    TextView _partOneItemName;

    IDictionary<string, int> _items;
    public IDictionary<string, int> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set => _items = value;
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        _items = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        //Setting the content view
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomePageLayout);

        //Making sure Btn has value upon creation
        UpdateBtnText();


        //Part 1 (which is linked to qauntyviewbtnpart1)
        _partOneItemName = FindViewById<TextView> 
        (Resource.Id.textPart1);
        //quantityViewBtnPart1
        var qtyPart1 = FindViewById<QuantityView> 
        (Resource.Id.quantityViewBtnPart1);
        qtyPart1.QuantityChanged += QtyPart1_QuantityChanged;

        var cartBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        cartBtn.Click += CartBtn_Click;

    }

    void QtyPart1_QuantityChanged(object sender, 
    QuantityView.OnQuantityChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        qtyPart1NewQty = e.NewQuantity;

        if (qtyPart1NewQty >= 1)
        {
            try
            {
                _items.Add(_partOneItemName.Text, qtyPart1NewQty);
            }
            catch 
            {
                _items.Remove(_partOneItemName.Text);
                _items.Add(_partOneItemName.Text, qtyPart1NewQty);
            }
        }

        var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        UpdateBtnText();
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the second activity where I want to display the keys and values of the dictionary:

```
public class BasketPageActivity : Activity, IItemList
{
    TextView basketTextView1;

    IDictionary<string, int> _items;
    public IDictionary<string, int> Items
    {
        get => Items;
        set => Items = value;
    }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        _items = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.BasketPageLayout);

        var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.itemListBtn);
        btn.Click += ItemListBtn_Click;

        basketTextView1 = FindViewById<TextView> 
        (Resource.Id.basketTextView);

        DisplayItemsOnScreen();
    }

    void ItemListBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(myIntent);

    }
    void DisplayItemsOnScreen()
    {
        basketTextView1.Text = "Keys : " + _items.Keys;

    }
}
```

So just to sumerise; the keys and values (string, int) in the first dictionary are not even going into the dictionary. In debug ill hover over dictionary values after they are suppose to be added and the value = 0 still.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: You are just creating (`new`) the `Dictionary` in each `Activity` and not passing any information between the Activity either with an application level instance, static instance, via bundle, via intent. etc...

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
How would i go about creating a static insance without creating a `(new)` `Dictionary`?